# Why the memory do not release after funciton call?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, heap-memory, htop

See my code below:

```
void foo() {
  std::ifstream f("data");
  string line;
  vector<string> r;
  while(getline(f, line)) {
    r.push_back(line);
  }
  f.close();
  r.resize(0);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  foo();
  cout << "load done" << endl;
  while(1) {;}
  return 0;
}
```

I use while(1) loop to check out the memory usage in `htop` tool, r may use 5GB `RES`, but after `load done` printed, `RES` still take 5GB. What's the problem?

Comment: vector returns the memory to the allocator, but the allocator probably don't return it to the OS, its not required to.

Comment: Please don't attach random tags to your questions. [C] has nothing to do with this; `std::vector<>` is not a C type at all.

Answer (score 2):

Resize doesn't guarantee that the underlying memory will be freed.

You should try with [shrink_to_fit](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/shrink_to_fit/), which will reduce the capacity of the contained to fit its size.

Comment: shortly thereafter the vector is destructed

Comment: @sp2danny That is a good point. Still, not returning 5gb back to the os is weird. Perhaps OPs observation is incorrect.

Comment: Resize is guaranteed _not_ to free any underlying memory (indirectly, at least, since it isn't allowed to invalidate any iterators).

Comment: but it is allocated in the stack space

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as the memory usage is checked after the vector object is destructed.

Comment: @xunzhang To be clear, the vector object is declared on the stack, but the data the vector object allocates is located on the heap.

Comment: @NeilKirk so you mean I must use resize(0) and shrink_to_fit before the function `foo` return?

Comment: @NeilKirk when the stack object deconstruct, why the deconstructor do not free the heap space?

Comment: @xunzhang The vector's destructor IS freeing the heap space. However, the heap manager for your program is not returning it to the OS, OR it has returned it to the OS but the OS has decided to keep it allocated to the program. It's common for OS to keep old allocations for programs in order to quickly satisfy a future memory request. You have to trust your OS will reclaim the memory if the system becomes short. Assuming you don't leak memory, don't worry about this.

Answer (score 0):

I think the erase and/or the clear function from vector klass would do that for you.
A very good documentation for vector is also on [cpusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)